# How to pass shell parameters when running a docker image?

Tags: bash, shell-script, docker

I've implemented a bash script which accepts the following parameters

```
SYNOPSIS
run.sh: run.sh [-H|-L|-P profile -D device [-R runtime]]
        list the fio profiles natively supported by the docker images or
        execute the selected profile on the targe devices within given
        duration, notice that the option L and P, D, R are mutually exclusive
                   
        Options:
          -H display this message
          -L list the profiles supported by the docker
          -P the profile name need to execute
          -D the device name(s) need to start FIO jobs, support format as /dev/vd[a-b]
          -R the exeuction time, optional, will run forever if not specified

# use case1：list all the profiles
# ./run.sh -L
###################################
#         Profiles supported      #
###################################
fio_profile_1.py
fio_profile_2.py
fio_profile_3.py
fio_profile_4.py

# use case2， start FIO job with profile_1 on vdb2 for 30 seconds
./run.sh -P fio_profile_1.py -D '/dev/vdb2' -R 30
```

I have wrappered this script into the docker, with following section in the docker file

```
EXPOSE 8000
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "/opt/runall.sh"]
```

and I am able to passed in the parameters by executing the docker with following commands?

```
docker run --privileged -v /dev:/dev -v workspace:/root  --rm fiotools/tool-aio:latest -P 'fio_profile_1.py' -D '/dev/vdb2' -R 39
```

However, I am facing another problem now, the script could display the output of the FIO during its executing as expect, but it could not be displayed when running with docker

```
# running with docker
# docker run --privileged -v /dev:/dev -v workspace:/root --attach stdout --rm fiotools/tool-aio:latest -P 'fio_profile_1.py' -D '/dev/vdb2' -R 39
working on the workspace /root/job.2023_02_06_16_21_32
# 

# running with shell inside the docker
# ./run.sh -P 'fio_profile_1.py' -D '/dev/vdb2' -R 39
working on the workspace /root/job.2023_02_06_16_25_13
Jobs: 1 (f=1): [m(1)][15.4%][r=46.9MiB/s,w=20.5MiB/s][r=5999,w=2622 IOPS][eta 00m:33s]
```

The bash script(run.sh) is nothing but just execute the fio command like in below, may I know  how should I possible output the FIO output?

```
    echo "working on the workspace ${target}"
    ... ...
    cd ${target} && fio --write_bw_log=rw --write_iops_log=rw --write_lat_log=rw --output=fio.output --output-format=json $jobfiles

    fio2gnuplot -t ${job}-bw -b -g -p '*_bw*'
    fio2gnuplot -t ${job}-iops -i -g -p '*_iops*'
```

Comment: I see you are running `docker run` with `-P 'fio_profile_1.py'` that will not send the output of `fio_profile_1.py` but just a *filename* which might not exist in your container. Also I'm not sure how are you getting the value of `-P 'fio_profile_1.py'`. Could you please add that to your question? using `-P "$(cat fio_profile_1.py)"` should send the output of the file in `$2` variable. But if you cannot change your script to detect a string and it must have a file then you should use my suggestion about: `docker run --rm -v /path/to/fio_profile_1.py:/fio_profile_1.py...`

Answer (score 0):

You should change `CMD ["/opt/run.sh"]` to `ENTRYPOINT [] ...`.

You can use this:

```
ENTRYPOINT /opt/run.sh $@
```

or (I suggest you use this option since the above one might have problems)

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "/opt/run.sh"]
```

<sup>Make sure that `/opt/run.sh` has execute permissions.</sup>

And for running the docker image (once this one has been built) run something like this:

```bash
docker run --rm image:latest -P fio_profile_1.py -D '/dev/vdb2' -R 30
```

Also note that in your script you have this:

```bash
-P the profile name need to execute
```

So in you run the docker image and specify that argument (and therefore the file) you will get an error because the file it does not exist in your docker container.

A possible solution is about passing the file as a volume by using `-v`, like this:

```bash
docker run --rm -v /path/to/fio_profile_1.py:/fio_profile_1.py image:latest -P fio_profile_1.py -D '/dev/vdb2' -R 30
```

Both the `-P fio_profile_1.py` and the filename specified in the volume `:/fio_profile_1.py` must have the same name.

---

Another workaround for running the python file is about passing its whole content as a parameter like this:

```bash
docker run --rm image:latest -P "$(cat fio_profile_1.py)" -D '/dev/vdb2' -R 30
```

And when you get the value of `-P` which is the content of `fio_profile_1.py` you can run the file using something like this:

```bash
# Assuming the content of python is script is in `$2`:
printf "%s\n" "$2" | python
```

Comment: thanks, it works now, however, I am not able to get the output of the FIO outside the docker, within the docker, I could get them like this:
```
#  ./runall.sh -P 'fio_profile_1.py' -D '/dev/vdb2' -R 39
Jobs: 1 (f=1): [m(1)][30.8%][r=46.9MiB/s,w=20.5MiB/s][r=5999,w=2620 IOPS][eta 00m:27s]
```

Comment: @wanglarry Did you use `-P "$(cat fio_profile_1.py)"`, if you did it then what is the content you get when the script `run.sh` is run? Please edit your question and those details as well as the content (if it is possible) of your script(s).